# Set named binding in PHP/PDO when having an OR on the same column

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm using PDO and prepared statements in my PHP application. I'm binding array values to the place holders in my query, something like this:

```
// This method is called twice from somewhere in my app:
// setWhere ( 'col1', 50 );
// setWhere ( 'col2', 60 );

function setWhere ( $column, $value )
{
    $this->bindings[$column] = $value;
}
```

Then i execute my query like so:

```
// This query is constructed by the same class (sort of an ORM wrapper)
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = :col1 OR col2 = :col2";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->execute ( $this->bindings );
```

It works fine like this. But what do i do when i need to select with an `OR` on the same column? Then i'd basically set an index in the array that already exists:

```
setWhere ( 'col1', 50 );
setWhere ( 'col1', 60 );
```

Which basically sets the `col1` index twice:

```
$this->bindings['col1'] = 50;
$this->bindings['col1'] = 60;
```

In this case it will never work.

How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: your setWhere() function going to be quite useless, as there are more than just one comparison operator. build your query dynamically using plain IF statements instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhh... just name it differently. As far as I can tell you're writing the query statically with bound vars, not building the query itself dynamically, so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = :val1 OR col1 = :val2";
setWhere ( 'val1', 50 );
setWhere ( 'val2', 60 );
$stmt = $this->db->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->execute ( $this->bindings );
```

If you *are* building the query dynamically, then you need to store 3 values for your conditions:

1. The column name, which need not be unique.
2. The parameter name, which must be unique.
3. The value you'd like to bind.

Something like:

```
function setWhere( $col, $param, $value ) {
  if( isset($this->bindings[$param]) ) {
    throw new Exception("Cannot double-bind parameter $param");
  }
  $this->bindings[$param] = array('col' => $col, 'val' => $value);
}

//function for $stmt->execute ( $this->getBindings );
function getBindings( ) {
  $ret = array();
  foreach($this->bindings as $key => $val) {
    $ret[$key] = $val['val'];
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two parameters with identical names in your query.

Param names in query and database table columns doesn't need to be named identical. PDO does just simple replace with param value processing, it doesn't build SQL query for you like any ORM does.

Comment: I know i can't have two parameters with identical names. That's my entire point. But since i'm using a few methods to construct my query i need to have a way to build up an array for my prepared statement somehow without having an identical name collision in my query like i have now.

Comment: @Vivendi okay, let's say you have this method. What will you do when you need AND instean of OR? :) Or XOR? I'm just trying to say that you design is not really a good idea: 1. You really shouldn't replace PDO placeholders with SQL code; 2. For your case I'd recommend using some ORM with criteria queries (i.e Doctrine) since you try to invent this approach.